# Ruby on rails : Bundle update giving errors in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, libxml2, ovirt

I am trying to run my rails server. When I first ran, I got an error like this

**No timezone data source could be found. To resolve this, either install TZInfo:**

I resolve the error by updating the x64 version of tzinfo-data in the gem file. After that when I ran **bundle update**, I am getting the following error

> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>           --with-libxml2-config
>           --without-libxml2-config
>           --with-pkg-config
>           --without-pkg-config extconf.rb:29:in `': The "libxml2" package isn't available. (RuntimeError)
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.3.0/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.3.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.3.0/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing ovirt-engine-sdk (4.3.0), and
>   Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install ovirt-engine-sdk
>   -v '4.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   fog was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
>       fog-ovirt was resolved to 1.1.6, which depends on
>         ovirt-engine-sdk

What could have possibly gone wrong? How to resolve this in Windows machines?

Comment: The "libxml2" package isn't available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834366/rails-installing-libxml2-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this might not be a good answer for you, but running Ruby on Rails on windows is a pain, and going to be terrible experience, try to set a dual boot with Ubuntu, Debian or any other linux distribution along side with windows and then you can develop with RoR as it should.